# How can I get a string path of an image in my assets folder

Tags: android

I need to pass a third party library the path of an image that is stored in my assets folder

I have read a few answers but none helped. I have tried 
`file:///android_asset/uk.jpg` and it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

> I need to pass a third party library the path of an image that is stored in my assets folder

There is no path. Your asset is not a file. It is an entry in a ZIP archive, nothing more.

Your options are:

1. Open an `InputStream` on the asset using `open()` from `AssetManager`, and pass that `InputStream` to the library
2. Open an `InputStream` on the asset using `open()` from `AssetManager`, use that to copy the asset to some location (e.g., [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html)), then pass the path to the file that you just created
3. Switch to a library that allows you to supply an `InputStream` or is Android-aware and supports assets directly